# Unity Error building Android Project : Gradle Daemon

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, build.gradle

I'm creating a little game on Android and all was alright since today.

I tried to add ads and IAP on my project and now when I try to build my project it gives me this errors : (I tried to upload the screen of my console but it tells me "Error parsing the uploaded files" so sorry)

- File C:\Users\bonel.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
- Unable to find player assembly: D:\Jeux\UNITY\SythwavesJumper\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll
- Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details Configure project :launcher WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
- Note: D:\Jeux\UNITY\SythwavesJumper\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. - CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.

And after it tells me that my build doesn't achieve (obviously). Please could you tell me if you know a solution? Great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your target API level is the minimum required for your Android device (Edit > Project Settings > Player), also set your 'managed stripping level' to minimal and add the folllowing into a link.xml config file in your Assets folder or a subdirectory of the assets folder:

```
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="UnityEngine.TestRunner" preserve="all"/>
</linker>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply !
How could I use the link.xml you're talking about ?

Comment: Just create a new XML file called 'link' in your Assets folder then add the tags I've mentioned above― any named assemblies you add won't be stripped by the UnityLinker when you build the application